# Correct verb for global sports

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Which verb should I use for sports if I want to mean all type of sport ( winter sport, summer sport, car races, footbal...etc)  In the next sentence

> He is **practicing** sports all the day, run, football, killing zombies...etc

Which verb is instead of practicing? Playing? Doing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that verbs that collocate with *sport(s)* need not collocate with an instance of it (such as *football*), and some sports aren't used with another verb at all. *Practicing* doesn't work in this context, though.

Comment: We would not use the present progressive here. Instead, use the simple present: _"He **practices** sports..."_ or _"He **plays** [at] sports..."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have doubts about which word fits better in a phrase I look at a **Concordancer**. [If you want to know more about it.](https://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/article/concordancers-elt)

I searched for:

1. "play sports" - 302 examples
2. "do sports" - 36 examples
3. "practice sports" - 3 examples

Based on that, I'd go with **"Playing sports"**.

This is the concordancer I used:
[Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/)